# How to use Sequel to select one field from database

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra, sequel

I am using Sinatra and Sequel with PostgreSQL.

After authentication, I want to welcome the user by printing their name but I cannot get only the value of the user's name from the database, it comes out as a hash.

The query is:

```
current_user = DB[:users].select(:username).where('password = ?', password).first
```

and the resulting piece of data is:

```
Welcome, {:username=>"Rich"}
```

which looks rather weird, I would prefer it to read "Welcome, Rich".

What am I doing wrong here? I tried the same query without 'first" at the end and that does not work either.

Comment: Methinks you should be using `current_user[:username]`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Solved: DB['select username from users where email_address = ?', email_address].each do |row|
    current_user =  row[:username]
    .....
    end
Just like PHP. LoL!

Comment: Of course! current_user[:username] works too. You see i am new to ruby and to ORM style database interaction, so it's all a bit of a mystery to me. Anyway, cheers!

Comment: Don't write your queries like `DB["some query"]`. You're missing the power of Sequel and ORMs when you do that. Read the [Sequel cheat sheet](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html) for a quick overview of how it's supposed to be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either pull the (single) column you selected out of the Hash you are given:

```ruby
current_user = DB[:users].select(:username).where('password=?', password).first[:username]
```

Or you can [map your results](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-select_map) to an array of usernames and pull the first:

```ruby
# Using a hash in the filter method is simpler than SQL placeholders.
current_user = DB[:users].filter(password:password).select_map(:username).first
```

But the best way is to get [only the user you care about](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-5B-5D), and then get the name:

```ruby
# Using [] on a dataset returns the first row matching the criteria
current_user = DB[:users][password:password][:username]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Sequel::Dataset#get. Also, as Phrogz points out, Sequel::Dataset#where can take a hash (it will securely escape values to prevent injection attacks).

```
current_username = DB[:users].where(password: password).get(:username)
```

There's also Sequel::Dataset#where_single_value, which is optimized for this exact situation:

```
current_username = DB[:users].select(:username).where_single_value(password: password)
```